# Options to build custom wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

I am asked to build a Wordpress site from scratch. The main requirements are: it has every sub module customized, custom styling and html. Modules should be able to be re used in different pages. But we don't want authors to design pages. Modules will have a standard view.

Is this possible with WP OOTB, in Gutenberg? Should I use elementor, or is that too much for my needs? Or should I ask designers to drive the designs based on WP existing themes and plugins?

I am new to WP, am used to other CMS systems but things are managed differently there, hence the confusion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use guttenberg blocks with ACF (Advanced custom fields). You can register new block and create block file (example: title-and-content.php). Create custom fields for that block and in created file echo custom fields.

```
<h1><?php echo get_field('title'); ?></h1>
```

Comment: The question was too generic, and probably need to be improved as well but your answer is limited and not answering to the doubt in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am new to WP, that's why the question. I have been researching tho, it seems like GenesisBlocks + Theme can help. Hopefully someone with WP experience can confirm.